# Elasticsearch integration with Kentico CMS

Tags: kentico

I want to know if there is any inbuilt feature kentico provides where one can use elastic search in Kentico CMS OR Is there a way we can integrate Elastic search with kentico CMS. Any suggestions or ideas will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should follow the Elastic search documentation to use their API how to integrate. In Kentico you can use e.g. [REST service](https://docs.xperience.io/integrating-3rd-party-systems/xperience-rest-service) or, [the integration bus](https://docs.xperience.io/integrating-3rd-party-systems/using-the-integration-bus) or, simply [the API](https://docs.xperience.io/13api) to expose the data you want to the Elastic search engine. There is no special magic. Simply said - it is up to you how you will get the data from Kentico and pass them to Elastic engine.